# "No direct method <init>([B)V " when using PduParser

Tags: java, android, mms

I'm trying to parse MMS messages by using [PduParser from AOSP.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/mms/+/4bfcd8501f09763c10255442c2b48fad0c796baa/src/java/com/google/android/mms/pdu/PduParser.java) I use `WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED` in my manifest in order to recieve MMS messages, and then I pipe them to a BroadcastReceiver that I've defined. However, when creating a new `PduParser` obejct, I get the following error.

```
12-21 20:14:43.063 25939-25939/com.ollien.smspusher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.ollien.smspusher, PID: 25939
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>([B)V in class Lcom/google/android/mms/pdu/PduParser; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduParser' appears in /system/framework/telephony-common.jar)
      at com.ollien.smspusher.MMSReceiver.onReceive(MMSReceiver.java:28)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3187)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The code snippest that causes the error is as follows

```
public class MMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        byte[] data = extras.getByteArray("data");
        PduParser parser = new PduParser(data);
    }
}
```

This is the relevant section of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MMSReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Not really sure where I'm going wrong. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: android jvm can't find class `PduParser` constructor. Check android SDK version or whether it is necessary package special lib.

Comment: I had to pull the code from AOSP. I added the `com/google/android/mms` package folder to my `app/java` folder. Do I need to do more to add this to compilation?

Comment: need remove `mms`  from you own src. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>([B)V in class Lcom/google/android/mms/pdu/PduParser; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduParser' appears in /system/framework/telephony-common.jar)`  . you'll find that jvm load `PduParse` from telephony-common.jar , but not from your apk.

Comment: If I don't have that package in my src, the package com.google.android.mms isn't found and I can't compile. How can I include it otherwise? I was looking at the source of QKSMS, and they include the `mms` package just as I did. https://github.com/moezbhatti/qksms/tree/master/QKSMS/src/main/java/com/google/android/mms

Comment: you can try like it, rename `com.google.android.mms.pdu` to `com.google.android.mms.pdu_alt`. ensure load classes from your code.

Comment: That worked perfectly. If you add this an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!